# R error using DBSCAN on Data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, cluster-analysis, dbscan

**Error in data - x : non-numeric argument to binary operator**
My code is as follows:

```
x <- as.factor(c(2, 2, 8, 5, 7, 6, 1, 4))

y <- as.factor(c(10, 5, 4, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9))

coordinates <- data.frame(x, y)

colnames(coordinates) <- c("x_coordinate", "y_coordinate")

print(coordinates)

point_clusters <- dbscan(coordinates, 2, MinPts = 2, scale = FALSE,
    method = c("hybrid", "raw", "dist"), seeds = TRUE, 
    showplot = 1, countmode = NULL)

point_clusters
```

But I'm getting following error while executing the above code:

```
> point_clusters <- dbscan(coordinates, 2, MinPts = 2, scale = FALSE, method = c("hybrid", "r ..." ... [TRUNCATED] 
Error in data - x : non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

I don't know what is the problem with above code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem as per my need. I saw somewhere that the **data** needs to be **numeric matrix**, although I'm not sure about that. So, here is what I did:

```
x <- c(2, 2, 8, 5, 7, 6, 1, 4)
y <- c(10, 5, 4, 8, 5, 4, 2, 9)
coordinates <- matrix(c(x, y), nrow = 8, byrow = FALSE)
```

Remaining code is same as above. Now it works fine for me.